# An everywhere discontinuous function

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces

As usual, $\mathbb R[x]$ denotes  the vector space of polynomials in one variable with real coefficients. It is easy enough (*and a good exercise for beginners*) to prove that the function $$P\to\|P\|=\max_{x\in [0,1]} |P(x)|$$ of $\mathbb R[x]$ in $\mathbb R_+$ defines a norm on 
$\mathbb R[x]$ (*then we can speak about continuity*).

Prove that for all $x_0\in \mathbb R; x_0\gt 1$ the function $f_{x_0}$ of $\mathbb R[x]$  in $\mathbb R$  defined by $$f_{x_0}(P)= P(x_0)$$ is discontinuous in every point $P\in \mathbb R[x]$

Comment: It is false. If $x_0\in[0,1]$, then $f_{x_0}$ is continuous

Comment: This is not true. In fact $f_{x_0}$ is continuous if and only if $x_0\in[0,1]$.

Comment: If you want a norm such that every $f_{x_0}$ is discontinuous you could for example define $||P||_1=\int_0^1|P(t)|\,dt$.

Comment: I have edited the lapsus. Thank you very much.

Comment: Pay attention please before deny. The question is true now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma: every continuous linear functional on a normed vector space is bounded, i.e. it has a finite operator norm.

Now the idea is that there are continuous functions which vanish on $[0,1]$ and are large at $x_0$, and therefore there are polynomials which are *close* to zero on $[0,1]$ but are large at $x_0$. This conclusion follows by Weierstrass' theorem. For details, let $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$, $1$ at $x_0$, and linear in between (the linearity is not important). Find a polynomial $p_n$ which is uniformly within $1/n$ of $f$. Then $P(p_n)=1$, but $\| p_n \| \leq 1/n$. Thus $\| P \|$, if $P$ were continuous, would need to be at least $n$, but this is impossible.

Comment: Good. Whitout use of explicit  theory, the sequence $\{P_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ defined by
$P_n(x)=(\frac xa)^n$; $1\lt a\lt x_0$ is such that $||P_n||=(\frac 1a)^n\to 0$ but $P_n(x_0)=(\frac {x_0}{a})^n\to \infty$

Comment: @Piquito Nice, that example does indeed work well. It also exposes the important fact that these examples require arbitrarily large degree. With a fixed maximum degree, the space is complete and homeomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^n$, so none of these phenomena can occur.

Comment: In finite dimension there are not examples of discontinuous linear function. In other words, what you say yourself in your comment. Best regards.